# ExtJS loading multiple stores from a single servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, extjs

I have 2 comboboxes on a window that have their store loaded when the window is created. I have a single servlet that calls the same function for both comboboxes we are trying to load however I have found that this causes problems and the stores don't get loaded correctly. Any ideas?

EDIT: So the more appropriate question would be: How to handle multiple requests on the same servlet? Is that a multithreading issue? I'd really like to avoid having to deal with that since I'm not that experienced even though this one seems easy...

Comment: Based on your description you have just a problem with your servlet when it get invoked by multiple requests. I don't think that it matter who is calling just that it are XHR requests. Therefore I recommend that you edit your question to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think there are problems if you call the same servlet from different XHR requests but the way to solve the loading problem is by calling the store.load functions in a cascading fashion inside each other's callback function:

```
store1.load({
 callback: function() {
  store2.load();
 }
});
```

This way stuff doesn't get in the way of the ajax request. However I still don't know why this is happening, the server is supposed to take care of the multithreading of the servlets...